# can flume 1.5 handle/transfer compressed file to hdfs sink

Tags: hadoop, flume, biginsights

can flume 1.5 handle/transfer compressed file to hdfs sink.
i tried with blobdeserializer and compressedstream and codec as gzip.
config options i used are as follows

```
agent1.sources.c1.deserializer =org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{file}
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.codeC = gzip
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.serializer.compressionCodec = gzip
```